# Convert FLV to MP4 using ffmpeg php

Tags: ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I have video with FLV format i want to covert that videos in to the MP4 format to using it in HTML5 video tag. Can anybody know the command to convert FLV to MP4.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use ffmpeg documentation or search older questions.

This is the example command

> ffmpeg -i input.flv -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a libfaac -q:a 100 output.mp4

Comment: FFmpeg has removed libfaac support.

Comment: Thanks i will check it and let you know.

Comment: Hello LordNeckbeard,

Comment: Hello LordNeckBeard,

Comment: I have try with above command but following error showing to me
[NULL @ 0x1d35380] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'aac'
aac: Invalid argument

Comment: use the -c:a copy parameter instead of -c:a libfaac, as LordNeckbeard said ffmpeg removed libffac support.